# ASP.NET session id: is it reliable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

According to that post: http://geekswithblogs.net/AnkitAgrawal/archive/2012/02/06/uniqueness-of-sessionid-and-guid.aspx

When you hover over the SessionId in ASP.NET application in VS, it says Unique SessionId. I don’t know how they can guarantee a unique id when there algorithm doesn’t support so. Below is the code:

```
    internal static string Create(ref RandomNumberGenerator randgen)
    {
        if (randgen == null)
        {
            randgen = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[15];
        randgen.GetBytes(data);
        return Encode(data);
    }
    private static string Encode(byte[] buffer)
    {
        char[] chArray = new char[0x18];
        int num2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i += 5)
        {
            int num4 = ((buffer[i] | (buffer[i + 1] << 8)) | (buffer[i + 2] << 0x10)) | (buffer[i + 3] << 0x18);
            int index = num4 & 0x1f;
            chArray[num2++] = s_encoding[index];
            index = (num4 >> 5) & 0x1f;
            chArray[num2++] = s_encoding[index];
            index = (num4 >> 10) & 0x1f;
            chArray[num2++] = s_encoding[index];
            index = (num4 >> 15) & 0x1f;
            chArray[num2++] = s_encoding[index];
            index = (num4 >> 20) & 0x1f;
            chArray[num2++] = s_encoding[index];
            index = (num4 >> 0x19) & 0x1f;
            chArray[num2++] = s_encoding[index];
            num4 = ((num4 >> 30) & 3) | (buffer[i + 4] << 2);
            index = num4 & 0x1f;
            chArray[num2++] = s_encoding[index];
            index = (num4 >> 5) & 0x1f;
            chArray[num2++] = s_encoding[index];
        }
        return new string(chArray);
    }
```

Comment: You just integrally copied the text of a blog post. Please read [ask] and share your research, elaborate on your question. There's been written a _lot_ about random, unique and GUIDs, what did you find?

Comment: You see from the provided code that session id is basically (cryptographically) random 15 byte (120bit) number, so it's not trully "unique" but chances of collision (generating duplicated session ids) is so low that can be ignored for this use case (session id).

Comment: This is closing in on the duplicate-Guids questions. You won't have a problem.

Comment: @Henk from the linked/copied blog: _"This causes a problem of non-unique GUID and SessionId generated [...] I have seen this in ASP.NET and java"_. [Citation needed].

Comment: He (the Blog poster) has seen the rng code in ASP.Net and Java and  imagines the problem.